# Completely hide Dock in OS X via the terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, dock

Is there a way of doing this?
I want to hide the Dock when my JFrame starts and then show it when the JFrame is disposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17326720/5416)

> There's is no API to control the Dock... at best, you can only suggest a tile to represent your app when present on the Dock.

Comment: I see.. I will try something else

Answer (score 0):

To my recollection, you can hide the Dock from an App (and/or the MenuBar) but this is achieved from the Info.plist file (and Terminal applications do not have one) or you can do this with NSApplication, but once again Terminal apps do not have such object.

However, you may want to transform your CLI application into a faceless GUI application, so you can benefit from a GUI application without ever displaying anything.